# How to keep Arguments always open inside Debugger

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Each time we step Continue or Step Over when we are debugging, the VARIABLES -> Arguments gets minimised. Is there a way to always keep that part open?

[image: arguments inside debugger]